# PL/SQL Implementation of Hungarian/Kuhn-Munkres Algorithm

Tags: sql, algorithm, plsql, oracle11g, hungarian-algorithm

Where is a PL/SQL implementation of the Hungarian/Kuhn-Munkres Algorithm?  There don't appear to be any online that I can find.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question.

Comment: Has been reformatted to q-and-a style

Comment: See [help/on-topic], point #4: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find one...so I made one. Now I want to share it with anyone else who needs it.  It has been tested and validated, and any additional comments are welcome.

https://github.com/manas1213/hungarian_algorithm

This is based on the comprehensive algorithm outlined at http://csclab.murraystate.edu/bob.pilgrim/445/munkres.html.